# You must import 'firebase/firestore' before using AngularFirestore

Tags: angular, firebase, typescript

Cordial saludo colegas, estoy realizando un crud con angular y firestore usando angularfire, al traer una colección me encuentro con el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He revisado las importaciones y no le encuentro nada mal, les adjunto el código del app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';
import {AngularFireModule} from '@angular/fire';
import {AngularFireAuthGuard} from '@angular/fire/auth-guard';
import {AngularFirestore} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { Page404Component } from './page404/page404.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { IndexComponent } from './index/index.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './auth/login/login.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Page404Component,
    NavbarComponent,
    IndexComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
  ],
  providers: [
    AngularFirestore,
    AngularFireAuthGuard
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

También adjunto el código de mi componente home donde estoy tratando de traer la colección

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {AngularFirestore} from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router, private db: AngularFirestore) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.db.collection('books').valueChanges()
      .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
  }
}
```

¿Alguna idea de que pueda estar mal?

Comment: Qué versión de angular y fire?

Comment: Hola , estoy usando la version "@angular/fire": "^6.0.0-rc.1", y angular 9.0.5

Comment: Esto te puede servir, hace mención a la versión 6 https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2310

Comment: Justo acabo de leer ese, ya encontré la solución y me funciono, gracias, voy a poner la solución aquí

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tienes instalado el '@angular/fire@next' para firebase, ahí tienes que pasas a tu componente a importar 'firebase/firestore' a tu componente de la siguiente manera:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {AngularFirestore} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
<!-- nuevo importe -->
import 'firebase/firestore';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router, private db: AngularFirestore) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.db.collection('books').valueChanges()
      .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
  }
}
```

Este error me dio por la versión de angularfire que tenía y lo solucione así, dejo el enlace para que lo chequen igual.

https://github.com/angular/angularfire

Answer (score 0):

El problema radica en la versión 6.0.0-rc.1 de angular fire, al parecer esta ya no importa el firestore en el AngularFireModule y por eso dispara ese error al momento de consultar, la solución que me funciono fue hacerle un downgrade al paquete angularfire a la versión 5.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Sólo haz la importación de firebase/firestore antes del AngularFirestore:

```
import 'firebase/firestore';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore'
```

;

Comment: No me lo tomes a mal pero me parece extremadamente corta y pobre de contenido para considerarse como wiki, si deseas que prevalezca asi será mejor que la edites y amplies el por que de tu solición, de lo contrario creo solo recibirás negativos